# Как правильно выполнить расчет и отображение данных

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

Необходимо сделать программу ввода значений, подсчет по формуле с применяем их, и по кнопке вывести результаты. Если дизайн программы создан в *QT Designer*, то с логикой проблема, формула написана, к окну вывода отображаться должна, кнопка  ничего не выводит.

Подскажите с кодом и как настроить логику приложения. 
Вводятся значения (`q, dp, b, PRO, Pbr`) на выходе (`k, R, Pie, Pp`).

rachet.py ---https://drive.google.com/file/d/14ybXViSztE6GZPkxKZ3X60FYHxbmr-QN/view?usp=sharing . Спасибо

```
import math
import sys
import self
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from rachet import Ui_MainWindow

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Calc)

class Calc:
    def __init__(self, q, dp, b, PRO, Pbr, k, R, Pp, Pie):
        self.input_q = q
        self.input_dp = dp
        self.input_b = b
        self.input_PRO = PRO
        self.input_Pbr = Pbr
        self.output_k = k
        self.output_R = R
        self.output_Pp = Pp
        self.output_Pie = Pie

        def k(self):
            op1 = 30 + 9.81 * self.input_dp
            op2 = 29.4 * self.input_dp + 10
            return op1 / op2

        def R(self):
            op1 = k * (self.input_q ** (1. / 3))
            return op1

        def Pp(self):
            op1 = 1 - math.exp(-(R * R))
            op2 = 2 * b * b

            return op1 / op2

        def Pie(self):
            op1 = Pp * Pbr * PRO
            return op1

        self.output_k.setText(str(k))
        self.output_R.setText(str(R))
        self.output_Pp.setText(str(Pp))
        self.output_Pie.setText(str(Pie))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы забыли опубликовать модуль `rachet.py`

Comment: @S.Nick , Спасибо, добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша задача может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
import math

# ??? import self

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#from rachet import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1036, 590)
        MainWindow.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:qconicalgradient(cx:0.488636, cy:0.602, angle:179.8, stop:0.329545 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:0.852273 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255))")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, -10, 641, 571))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background:none;")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../Downloads/free-icon-nuclear-blast-4839072.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 70, 41, 31))
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 15pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:none;")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 220, 491, 31))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 20pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:#000;")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.input_b = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_b.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 120, 131, 31))
        self.input_b.setStyleSheet("color:#ffb703;\n"
"font: 20pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color:#000;\n"
"border- radius : 30;\n"
"")
        self.input_b.setObjectName("input_b")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 20, 251, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(9)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"font: 75 20pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:#000;\n"
"border- radius: 30;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"font: 20pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#f3f700;\n"
"background-color:#35362d;\n"
"border- radius: 30;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"font: 20pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#deb316;\n"
"background-color:#8c897b;\n"
"border- radius: 30;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"piqtgraph")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.input_PRO = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_PRO.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 220, 131, 31))
        self.input_PRO.setStyleSheet("color:#ffb703;\n"
"font: 20pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color:#000;\n"
"border- radius : 30;\n"
"")
        self.input_PRO.setObjectName("input_PRO")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 361, 31))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 20pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:#000;")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 170, 531, 31))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 20pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:#000;")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.input_q = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_q.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 20, 131, 31))
        self.input_q.setStyleSheet("color:#ffb703;\n"
"font: 20pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color:#000;\n"
"border- radius: 60;\n"
"")
        self.input_q.setObjectName("input_q")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 421, 31))
        self.label_3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:#000;\n"
"")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.input_dp = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_dp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 70, 131, 31))
        self.input_dp.setStyleSheet("color:#ffb703;\n"
"font: 20pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color:#000;\n"
"border- radius : 30;\n"
"")
        self.input_dp.setObjectName("input_dp")
        self.input_Pbr = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_Pbr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 170, 131, 31))
        self.input_Pbr.setStyleSheet("color:#ffb703;\n"
"font: 20pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color:#000;\n"
"border- radius : 30;\n"
"")
        self.input_Pbr.setObjectName("input_Pbr")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 20, 31, 31))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 15pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:none;")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 120, 31, 31))
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 15pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:none;")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 371, 31))
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 20pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:#000;")
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 340, 361, 31))
        self.label_12.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 15pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:#fff;")
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 400, 361, 31))
        self.label_13.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 15pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:#fff;")
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 450, 361, 31))
        self.label_14.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 15pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:#fff;fff")
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 500, 361, 31))
        self.label_15.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 15pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#ffb703;\n"
"background-color:#fff;fff")
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 60, 399, 269))
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("background:none")
        self.label_10.setText("")
        self.label_10.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../Downloads/explosion_PNG15394.png"))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 70, 251, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(9)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"font: 75 20pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:#000;\n"
"border- radius: 30;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"font: 20pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#f3f700;\n"
"background-color:#35362d;\n"
"border- radius: 30;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"font: 20pt \"TypoUpright BT\";\n"
"color:#deb316;\n"
"background-color:#8c897b;\n"
"border- radius: 30;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"piqtgraph")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.output_k = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_k.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 340, 81, 31))
        self.output_k.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(255, 255, 255)")
        self.output_k.setText("")
        self.output_k.setObjectName("output_k")
        self.output_R = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_R.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 400, 81, 31))
        self.output_R.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(255, 255, 255)")
        self.output_R.setText("")
        self.output_R.setObjectName("output_R")
        self.output_Pp = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_Pp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 450, 81, 31))
        self.output_Pp.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(255, 255, 255)")
        self.output_Pp.setText("")
        self.output_Pp.setObjectName("output_Pp")
        self.output_Pie = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_Pie.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 500, 51, 31))
        self.output_Pie.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(255, 255, 255)")
        self.output_Pie.setText("")
        self.output_Pie.setObjectName("output_Pie")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1036, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "МПа"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите вероятность 2 :"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Произвести расчет"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите защищённость  :"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите вероятность 1  :"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите мощность  :"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мт"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "м"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите точность  :"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Коэффициент защищенности  :"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Радиус зоны   :"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вероятность    :"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Эффективность  :"))
  
# ???  
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить"))        # ???
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Calc)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.calc)
        
    def calc(self):
        q = self.input_q.text()
        dp = self.input_dp.text()
        b = self.input_b.text()
        PRO = self.input_PRO.text()
        Pbr = self.input_Pbr.text()
        
        if not q or not dp or not b or not PRO or not Pbr:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(None, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Заполните все поля ввода.'
            )
            return
            
        try:
            q = float(q)
            dp = float(dp)
            b = float(b)
            PRO = float(PRO)
            Pbr = float(Pbr)
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(None, 
                'Внимание', 
                f'Заполните правильно поля ввода \n {e}.'
            )
            return    

        if b == 0 or PRO == 0 or Pbr == 0:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(None, 
                'Внимание', 
                'division by zero.'
            )
            return            
        
        k = self._k(dp)
        self.output_k.setText(f'{k:.2f}')
        
        R = self._R(k, q)
        self.output_R.setText(f'{R:.2f}')  

        Pp = self._Pp(R, b)
        self.output_Pp.setText(f'{Pp:.2f}')
        
        Pie = self._Pie(Pp, Pbr, PRO)        
        self.output_Pie.setText(f'{Pie:.2f}')

    def _Pp(self, R, b):
        op1 = 1 - math.exp(-(R * R))
        op2 = 2 * b * b
        return op1 / op2

    def _Pie(self, Pp, Pbr, PRO):
        op1 = Pp * Pbr * PRO
        return op1        
        
    def _R(self, k, q):
        op1 = k * (q ** (1. / 3))
        return op1

    def _k(self, dp):
        op1 = 30 + 9.81 * dp
        op2 = 29.4 * dp + 10
        return op1 / op2
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Осталась лишь работа с дизайном.Выручили!

Comment: @GomerSimson пожалуйста.